# BehaviorSubject and conditional Component display

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-directives, angular2-services, behaviorsubject

I've got this simple Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HighlightsService {
  private _highlitTab: string = '';
  highlitTab$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(this._highlitTab);

  public get tab(): string {
    return this._highlitTab;
  }

  public set tab(val: string) {
    this._highlitTab = val;
    this.highlitTab$.next(this._highlitTab);
  }
}
```

Which is set in my tabs:

```
(select)="highlightsService.tab = 'show component0'
```

Now in my view which shows multiple directives, how do I conditionally show them?

```
<app-component0 [hide]="highlightsService.highlitTab$ | async"></app-component0>
<app-component1 [show]="highlightsService.highlitTab$ | async"></app-component0>
```

Obviously that won't work, because there's no `===`. Is there some `ngSwitch` equivalent?

How do I conditionally show `Component`s based on `BehaviourSubject` value?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I don't think that async pipe will work with just BehaviorSubject anyway.  This is how I would do it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HighlightsService {
  private _highlitTab: string = '';
  private _highlitTab$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(this._highlitTab);
  public highlitTab$: Observable<string> = this._highlitTab$.asObservable();

  public get tab(): string {
    return this._highlitTab;
  }

  public set tab(val: string) {
    this._highlitTab = val;
    this._highlitTab$.next(this._highlitTab);
  }
}
```

The value of the `_highlitTab` variable is also questionable because you can get it within the service with `this._highlitTab$.getValue()`.

Now, in your component, you inject the `HighlightsService` as you seem to already be doing, and subscribe to it, probably in `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.highlightsService.highlitTab$
    .filter(value => value)
    .subscribe(value => this.hightlitTab = value);
```

The filter line ensures that you don't get an empty value (the initialization value).  This may not be your desired behavior.

Finally, you can now show or hide whichever tab you want by comparing it to the updated local value of `highlitTab`.  If it were me, I probably just pass the `highlitTab` value on down to the child component, and that component can decide whether to show itself or not.

```
<child-component0 [highlitTab]='hightlitTab'></child-component>
```

Comment: Thanks, however that would work however then I would need the `onInit`/`onDestroy` boilerplate for un/subscribe handling. The `async` pipe does work BTW. What I'm looking for is a solution with all the logic in the Service and component.html. Will keep things clean.

Comment: I don't really understand your opposition to logic in the component.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up moving the tab checking logic to the `Service`. Now my `Component`s don't need to subscribe.